# Make text background transparent

Tags: html, css

My problem is I have created a [website](http://karni-imitation-jewellerys.page.tl/) using an online website creator for free. The only way to edit my website is through the builder. They have provided me a `<head>` tag where I can copy paste code to change.

In my web page I want to make my text background transparent. I.e. make background same as my website background. Thank you for help.

Comment: You have some mistake in html. You forgot to close <style> in line 310 and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your head tag, find a style tag and add this on a new line.

```
#content {background-color:transparent}
```

If you can't find a style tag, create one:

```
<style>
  #content {background-color:transparent}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you use 'rgba' color mode.
r red
g geen
b blue
a alpha (opacity)

You can find rgb values of any color in adobe Photoshop or any other image editors in market.

[image: rgb values in photoshop] 
in the given image the color is"#d10f0f"

You can write it in css

```
background-color:#d10f0f;
```

aslo in rgba

```
background-color:rgba(209,15,15,0.5);
```

and here you can change the transparency of the color by adjusting the last value "0.5" you can choose any value between 0.1 to 1.